# How to set count of c# without altering capacity?

Tags: c#, list, optimization, count, capacity

I know exactly how many items I want to keep in a list, they are ordered, I only need it to finish at an specific index I know, but I don't want to alter the capacity or use TrimExcess in order to make it smaller, otherwise after adding an item again it will double the size of the list again.

How can I set the Count instead of using Remove or RemoveAt or RemoveRange?.

My priority is optimization of speed for this operation.

Important: I know I can use an array, but I am not allowed. Also, I'm adding items and removing them all the time. I just want the capacity to stay around a similar amount which I don't know exactly but it will stabilize.

Comment: can you be more specific and show us some few examples

Comment: You can't and theres' no point to it. `Count` returns the number of *actual* items. The only way to change it is to add or remove items. `Capacity` isn't related so `TrimExcess` won't affect the count.

Comment: *Why* do you want to make it smaller if it's going to increase? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using arrays instead of lists. you can set the size of the array when it's instantiated: `string[] myArray = new string[100];`

Comment: "I know exactly how many items I want to keep in the list" If you know the size, then why aren't you using an array?

Comment: You can only change the Count by adding or removing items.  So consider to stop adding any more if you think it is getting too much.  This tends to not be terribly practical.  Note that doubling only occurs at specific sizes (0, 4, 8, 16 etc), you'd first consider setting the Capacity up front.

Comment: I added a comment. I can't use an array in this case. I'm forced to use it.

Comment: Removing the last element of a `List<T>` is very efficient. Take a look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#3d46113cc199059a). Are you removing elements at random positions in the list or the last one?

Comment: Why are you forced to use a list?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Where are you adding and removing items?  Do you insert items in the middle, at the beginning, or do you only add them at the end?  You can use RemoveAt() sometimes but not to keep the size of the list in check?  You need to clearly specify what you need help doing and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove elements, the Capacity won't change. So if you don't use `TrimExcess()`, the Capacity will only ever increase (to the maximum you ever used for this list). So there's no performance penalty in removing elements again. You can set the initial capacity in the constructor, which is a good idea if you know how many elements you'll be using (or have an estimate for it), because that will remove the overload of the doubling while initially building up the list.

Note: Insert/Remove in a list is still O(n), because the elements eventually need to be compied around (unless you operate only at the tail end of the list).

Comment: Ok! So using RemoveRange with the last items... will be O(n) or not?

Comment: RemoveRange() with items at the back of the list will be O(1), RemoveRange() with items anywhere in the list is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array and (in C# 8.0 onwards) use Indices and Ranges with slicing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges

Comment: Thanks. But I can't use C#8 right now. It's not integrated .